# что не так с формой для регистрации и почему не работает?

Tags: python, django

**Это - forms.py**

```
 class RegistrationForm(Form):
        fullname = CharField(
            label='Имя',
            max_length=100,
            error_messages={'required': 'Укажите имя'})
        email = CharField(
            label='e-mail',
            widget=PasswordInput(),
            error_messages={'required': 'Укажите e-mail'})
        username = CharField(
            label='username',
            max_length=100,
            error_messages={'required': 'Укажите логин'})
        password = CharField(
            label='Пароль',
            widget=PasswordInput(),
            error_messages={'required': 'Укажите пароль'})
        password_again = CharField(
            label='Пароль (еще раз)',
            widget=PasswordInput(),
            error_messages={'required': 'Укажите пароль еще раз'})
    def clean(self):
            if self.cleaned_data.get('password') != self.cleaned_data.get('password_again'):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Пароли должны совпадать!')
            return self.cleaned_data
```

**Это - models.py**

```
class registry(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
     login = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     password = models.CharField(max_length=8)
     password_again =  models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

**это - часть html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
                       {{ form.as_p }}
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Зарегистрироваться
                            </button>
                           {% csrf_token %}
                        </form>
```

**Это - вьюха.**

```
def registry(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Форма верна!')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'registry.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Что именно не работает, стоит уточнить. Ваша view не выполняется?

Comment: я нажимаю "зарегистрироваться" и ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Aniri Страница с текстом 'Форма верна!' грузится?

Comment: нет, не грузится

Comment: Как минимум action у формы - пустой, еще и button не типа submit

Comment: @Basalex а можно пожалуйста как это лолжно выглядить?